# Control shadows in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I find a way to control shadows: colors, shapes, intensity. I googled it before and had found that I can use custom pass or must write shader. But it seems difficult for me. Is there way to do it in shader graph? Or I must start to study HLSL?
Could you give me a right direction how I can study it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by controlling shadows? Because depending on what you are doing there are different approaches.

Comment: I want to draw shadows more darker, quivering, various sizes and geometric shapes. But first aim is drawing black shadows from transparent object.

Answer (score 0):

In the basic sense of configuring shadows, you will need to combine light casting into the scene and the `Mesh Renderer`. There is also a whole section in Unity in the `Mesh Renderer` where you can configure the lighting scale, parameters and baking vs real-time rendering. Just like real life, focus on the lighting for the shadows to be the way you want them.

Unless you mean shaders of materials, since you mentioned passing. For that, you can look on the official [Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadersOverview.html).

Comment: I read it early... But I mean I want to control colors, shapes. Now I want to draw shadow from transparent object that more darker and bigger than shadows from another objects.

Comment: I see. Well, you can also look into the `Maps` of the materials you are trying to darken. There are some subsections in the `Standard Shader` of the Unity Manual you can look into: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderContextAndContent.html